# Incremental Learning of SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

What are some real world applications where incremental learning of (machine learning) algorithms is useful? 
Are SVMs preferred for such applications?
Is the solution more computationally intensive than retraining with the set containing old support vectors and new training vectors ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a well known incremental version of SVM:

- http://www.isn.ucsd.edu/pubs/nips00_inc.pdf

However, there are not much existing implementations available, maybe something is in Matlab:

- http://www.isn.ucsd.edu/svm/incremental/

The advantage of that approach is that it offers exact leave-one-out evaluation of
the generalization performance on the training data

Answer (score 0):

theres is a trend towards large, "out of core" datasets, which are often streamed in from network, disk, or a database. a real world example is the popular nyc taxi dataset, which, at 330+gb, cannot be easily tackled by desktop statistical models.

svms, as a "one batch" algorithm, must load the entire dataset into memory. as such they are not preferred for incremental learning. rather, learners like logistic regression, kmeans, neural nets, which are capable of partial learning, are preferred for such tasks.